# Is it safe to move unique_ptr from a container and erase it?

Tags: c++, multithreading, locking, unique-ptr

I am wondering the following pattern is safe to use and recommendable? First, I'd like to move a unique_ptr found from a container to another temporary unique_ptr and then erase it from the container. Then, call an actual method using the moved pointer.

This is to avoid locking the entire container while calling some expensive method.

Please see the following example:

```
std::unordered_map<string, std::unique_ptr<Sample>> samples;

std::unique_ptr<Sample> ptr_to_remove;

// Lock (reader lock) samples here.
auto it = samples.find(name);
if (it != samples.end()) {
   ptr_to_remove = std::move(it->second);
   samples.erase(it);
}
// Unlock samples here.

if (ptr_to_remove) {
    ptr_to_remove->DoSomeExpensiveTask();
}
```

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: it->second is a `Sample` object, not a `unique_ptr`. Did you mean `std::unordered_map<std::string, std::unique_ptr<Sample>> samples;`  ? (For the code to compile).

Comment: A.S.H, yes. that's correct :) Updated the question

Comment: Mikel, it seems working well. But I was wondering if there are any hidden side effects or something...

Comment: I would write an answer, but it would only be 3 characters, and the system requires 30.

Comment: Benjamin, so it is 3 characters not 2 characters, right? :)

Comment: I would respond to that comment, but the response would only be 3 characters, and the system requires 15.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley Since brevity is the soul of wit and tediousness the limbs and outward flourishes, I will be brief...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's safe.

The value type of `unordered_map` isn't `const`, so you're allowed to modify it. Moving from a `unique_ptr` is safe. Erasing the item from the map will invoke the destructor on the `unique_ptr`, which will destroy the now-empty `unique_ptr`, which is also safe.

The only potentially unsafe parts of your code example are:

- The comments about `// lock` should be replaced with a scoped lock guard.
- I realize this is probably just for exposition, but you're invoking `DoSomeExpensiveTask` on your local `unique_ptr` without first checking if it has a value or not.

Comment: Oh, I see. Thanks. Updated the question (adding the code checking if the pointer has a value)